# Multithread downloading

Tags: wget, xargs

I have 464 links in txt file, and i want to download them as fast as it is possiblle. 
Each url is a link to json file.

TXT File:
http://textuploader.com/ddgry

i ve tried `cat urls | xargs -n 1 -P 464  wget -q`
and the time is

```
real    0m30.924s
user    0m1.932s
sys 0m0.368s
```

is it any faster way to do it?

Comment: Download and use `gnu parallel` instead of xargs.

Comment: nope, time is 1m02s :(